# How to get Sogou Pinyin IME work properly in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: input-method, chinese, fcitx

After installing Ubuntu 22.04, I have trouble getting `Sogou Pinyin IME` work properly.
The issue I'm facing is that the trigger key combination `[Ctrl + Space]` toggles the IME icon on and off in the right corner of the top panel, but the IME widget (see screenshot below) won't always appear on the screen and IME conversion won't happen, letters appear in the place of input in the usual way, as with no IME. The only thing I see in this case is a 'toast' message that says 'sogoupinyin' and disappears after a second. Sometimes the widget does appear and IME conversion works, however. I am unable to figure out what is causing this issue.

In the past I followed this "recipe" for installing Sogou Pinyin on Ubuntu and it has always worked reliably. Here's the procedure, I have followed.

- After installing the system, open `Language Support` and allow the operating system to install the missing files it wants to install
- Then click `Install/Remove languages`, and select both Simplified and Traditional Chinese, wait for the installation of Chinese files/packages
- Restart system/logout
- Install `fcitx`, `fcitx-pinyin`, `fctix-googlepinyin` (not sure which of the latter two was actually necessary, I used `synaptic` here to take care of installing all the dependencies)
- Select `fcitx` in `Language Support` to be the default input method system
- Restart system/logout
- Download the .deb file from [Sogou's website](https://pinyin.sogou.com/linux?r=pinyin)
- Run `sudo dpkg -i sogoupinyin_[version-numer].deb` (and fix the dependency problems with `sudo apt-get install -f`)
- Restart system/logout
- Hit `[Ctrl + Space]`. At this point the IME widget would appear and things would work as expected.

With jammy, installing and troubleshooting Sogou Pinyin has become a time consuming hassle.

Version numbers:

```
Ubuntu Desktop 22.04
fcitx version: 4.2.9.8
fcitx-googlepinyin: 0.1.6-5
fcitx-pinyin: 1:4.2.9.8-5
Sogou Pinyin package: sogoupinyin_4.0.1.2123_amd64.deb
```

Here's what I mean by 'icon':
[image: Sogou IME icon]

Here's what I mean by 'widget':
[image]

---

EDIT: Here's a workaround that has "fixed" the problem. Install Sogou Pinyin from [an older release](https://www.ubuntukylin.com/applications/40-en.html).

---

EDIT 2: `apt policy fcitx`

```
fcitx:
  Installed: 1:4.2.9.8-5
  Candidate: 1:4.2.9.8-5
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.2.9.8-5 500
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 4):

I find a way to fix this:

when I try to run "/opt/sogoupinyin/files/bin/sogoupinyin-service", it give me  "libgsettings-qt.so.1 not found" error, so just install deps with:

sudo apt install libgsettings-qt-dev

And then logout, relogin, every thing works.

Answer (score 2):

If you install a Chinese language in Ubuntu 22.04, Language Support pulls fcitx5. AFAIK Sogou is not yet adapted to fcitx5, but only fcitx (i.e. fcitx4). And fcitx5 and fcitx4 can't co-exist.

That *might* be the reason why you run into difficulties.

The Ubuntu Kylin considerations in [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=976603) are related.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 installed Fcitx 4 for me (see the version number above).

Comment: @imrek: I see. But I doubt that Ubuntu did that. Maybe you did by installing e.g. the `fcitx` package manually or since the `sogoupinyin` package depends on it.

Comment: I've added the output of `apt policy` for `fcitx`. The version I have came from the repositories for jammy.

Comment: @imrek: Right, I didn't mean to say that `fcitx` is not in the jammy archive.. (it is). But in jammy, if you install a Chinese language, it pulls (or tries to pull) `fcitx5`. That was true also in Ubuntu 21.10, but not in previous Ubuntu versions. And since `fcitx` and `fcitx5` can't co-exist in 22.04, the resulting conflict may result in inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason is that Ubuntu 22.04 enables `Wayland` by default. For `Wayland` you may export the environments variables elsewhere:

In `/etc/environment`, add these:

```bsh
GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx"
```

Then reboot. This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

sogoupinyin-service misses two Qt libraries:

sudo apt install libgsettings-qt1 libqt5qml5

Then reboot. It works well now.